# Type annotations for base and inherited classes - is Generic and TypeVar the right approach?

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Say I have a base class

```py
from typing import List, Optional

class Node:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.children: List['Node'] = []
    ...
```

and a subclass

```py
class PropertiesNode(Node):
    def __init__(
        self, name: str, properties: List[str], inherit: Optional['PropertiesNode']
    ) -> None:
        Node.__init__(self, name)
        self.properties = set(properties)
        if inherit:
            self.properties.update(inherit.properties)
            self.children = deepcopy(inherit.children)
            for child in self.children:
                child.properties.update(properties)
                # ^ ERR: "Node" has no attribute "properties"  [attr-defined]
```

As you can see, mypy (rightly) flags an error there, as `Node.children` was explicitly given a type of `List[Node]`.

So I read up on generic types, and it seems to me the solution is to use `TypeVar`s and `Generic`:

```py
from typing import Generic, List, Optional, TypeVar

N = TypeVar('N', bound='Node')
P = TypeVar('P', bound='PropertiesNode')

class Node(Generic[N]):
    def __init__(self: N, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.children: List[N] = []

class PropertiesNode(Node[P]):
    def __init__(
        self: P, name: str, properties: List[str], inherit: Optional[P]
    ) -> None:
        Node.__init__(self, name)
        self.properties = set(properties)
        if inherit:
            self.properties.update(inherit.properties)
            self.children = deepcopy(inherit.children)
            for child in self.children:
                child.properties.update(properties)
```

However, now when I instantiate the classes, I get

```py
foo = Node("foo")
# ^ ERR Need type annotation for "foo"  [var-annotated]
bar = PropertiesNode("bar", ["big", "green"], None)
# ^ ERR Need type annotation for "bar"  [var-annotated]
```

Now, I could silence these by doing

```py
foo: Node = Node("foo")
bar: PropertiesNode = PropertiesNode(...)
```

but why does that silence it - I'm not giving mypy any new info there? The more I think about, the less `Generic` seems like the right choice, because the thing is: all instances of `Node` or `PropertiesNode` will have `self.children` that are of exactly the same type as `self`.

But if I remove the `Generic[N]` from `class Node(Generic[N]):`, I end up with the original error again:

```py
class PropertiesNode(Node):
    ...
                child.properties.update(properties)
                # ^ ERR "N" has no attribute "properties"  [attr-defined]
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two things going on here

**1. Generics**

Annotating a variable `foo: Node`, where `Node` is a generic class, is equivalent to annotating it as `foo: Node[typing.Any]`. It will silence MyPy on the default settings, but if you choose to use MyPy with some of the stricter flags set to `True` (which I recommend doing!), you'll find that MyPy still flags this kind of thing as an error.

If you run this in MyPy:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, List

N = TypeVar('N', bound='Node')

class Node(Generic[N]):
    def __init__(self: N, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.children: List[N] = []

foo: Node = Node("foo")
reveal_type(foo)
```

You'll find that MyPy will come back to you with a message similar to:

```
Revealed type is "__main__.Node[Any]"
```

(N.B. `reveal_type` is a function that MyPy recognises, but that will fail if you try to use it at runtime.)

To get MyPy to flag unparameterised generics as errors, run MyPy with the command-line argument `--disallow-any-generics`. Doing so will mean MyPy will flag the following errors:

```
main.py:3: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "Node"
main.py:10: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "Node"
```

Forcing you to adjust your code to the following:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, List, Any

N = TypeVar('N', bound='Node[Any]')

class Node(Generic[N]):
    def __init__(self: N, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.children: List[N] = []

foo: Node[Any] = Node("foo")
```

This makes MyPy happy once again, and says the same thing that you said in your original code, but more explicitly.

However...

**2. I don't think it's necessary to use Generics in this situation**

You don't *have* to inherit from generic in order to annotate the `self` argument in `__init__` with a `TypeVar`. Moreover, as you say in your question, inheriting from `Generic` just doesn't really make sense here, either from the perspective of MyPy or from other humans reading your code. I'd modify your code like so:

```
from typing import List, Optional, TypeVar, Any
from copy import deepcopy
    
N = TypeVar('N', bound='Node')
P = TypeVar('P', bound='PropertiesNode')

class Node:
    def __init__(self: N, name: str, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.children: List[N] = []
    
class PropertiesNode(Node):
    def __init__(self: P, name: str, properties: List[str], inherit: Optional[P], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self.properties = set(properties)
        if inherit is not None:
            self.properties.update(inherit.properties)
            self.children: List[P] = deepcopy(inherit.children)
            for child in self.children:
                child.properties.update(properties)
```

Now we have annotations that will make MyPy happy, even on the strictest settings, and they even make sense to humans as well!

N.B. I changed two other things in your code here:

1. I added `*args, **kwargs` parameters to your `__init__` methods — as written, they violated the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle?wprov=sfti1). By adding in these parameters, you avoid that issue.
2. I changed your test from `if inherit` to `if inherit is not None` — lots of things can be `False`-y in python, so it's much safer to test by identity when testing if a value is `None` or not.